# (Laravel-Vue) - fetch data in object inside an object using v-for

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

I'm relatively new in incorporating vue to laravel. 
My question is how do I return a data from an object inside an object, using v-for.

Data hierarchy:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            "project": {
                name: "john",
                age: "21",
                "client": {
                    name: "stan",
                    age: 18
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In laravel I incorporate the model relationship (one to manny).
1 client can have many projects.

I'm having a bit of obstacles here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can u share your code or some expected output?

Comment: as you describe that your relationship is (one to many ) with client model. your data structure should be something like that ```{
    data:[
        {
            "client":{
                name:"stan",
                age:"18", 
                "projects":[
                    {
                        name:"john",
                        age:21
                    },{
                        name:"doe",
                        age:23
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with? With setting up the relationship in the model in Laravel? Or with using the data in the template? Is the data hierarchy you posted what you're already getting from Laravel or what you want to get?

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from **client object** using v-for. 

`<tr v-for="project from projects" :key="project.id">
<td>{{project.client}}</td>
</tr>`

The data hierarchy is from project to client because i was calling it from ProjectController.

Comment: Looks like you need to you `project.project.id` and `project.project.client` in the `v-for` above.

Comment: Not working for v-for.

Comment: For others that are having the same problem, I think i found the solution after days of research lol. since you cannot loop though nested object using v-for.
You need use state management, in my case i tried to use vuex, Basically state management is like managing your data from one single source of truth. It allows you to use third degree call from the loop. {{mydata.details.subDetails}}

For documentation : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/